# Rails Active Job usage , or running watcher thread automatically with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activejob

It's nice to see Rails 4.2 come with Active Job as a common interface for background jobs. But I can't find how to start a worker in the document. It seems that the document is still immature (e.g. the right version of Sneakers is only referred to in Rails' `Gemfile`), so I'm not sure if the "running workers" part is not in Active Job or just not mentioned in docs.

So with Active Job, do I still need to manually start the job watcher threads like `sidekiq` or in my case, `rake sneakers:run`? If so, where should I put these commands to let `rails server` run these parallel tasks automatically in a develop environment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ActiveJob is just a common interface. You still need the backend gem, and you still need to launch it separately from your server (it is a separated process, which is the objective).

Sample using resque:

In the Gemfile:

```
gem 'resque'
```

In the terminal, launching a worker:

```
bin/resque work
```

The case is similary when using sidekick, delayed job or something else.

If you want to launch the server & worker in a single command, you can create a short bash script for it, but I would advise not doing so: having two separated console helps to watch what is happening on each side (web app & worker).

A better solution would be to use the [foreman](http://ddollar.github.io/foreman/) gem to manage starting & stopping your process.

You can create a simple Procfile with the processes to start:

```
web: bundle exec rails s
job: bundle exec resque work
```

And then just start both using foreman:

```
foreman start
```

By default, foreman will interleave the logs of the process in the console, but this can be configured.

Comment: +1 for suggesting the `foreman` gem. Makes it easy to manage multiprocess apps during development.

Comment: Thanks, that's very clear and helpful. I'm playing with foreman, not sure how I managed to not know it all these days.

Comment: For anyone search to this question for a sneakers solution, sneakers requires [some additional config](https://gist.github.com/cristianbica/b3a7edf2a8ff81dbafa3) at this time, originally provided by **Seuros**  from reddit.

Comment: [And a rubygem for sneakers](http://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/2epepm/needing_help_with_rails_new_active_job/ck24dvx)

Answer (score 1):

You still have to run the job thread watcher.